# PIL: how to draw € on an image with draw.text?

Tags: python, python-imaging-library, python-unicode

I have a title ("cadeau check 50 €") in a form value that I want to write to a background image with `arial.ttf`. My text is correct but for the euro sign. I have 2 [] in place. I don't know where the problem is coming from. Is this an encoding problem in PIL, or have I a problem with the font?

Comment: You should edit your question with what you posted as a comment to the answer below; that way everybody who comments/answers is notified of the new activity.  But your comment leads me to believe that your problem is not with PIL, it is with how you are obtaining the text in the first place.  Edit your post with a small (<50 lines) complete program that reproduces the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe use Unicode strings?? Like u'cadeau check 50 €' ... Now, does also your font have the corresponding glyphs?

Comment: Thanks for the answers , but i have already tried with different encodings, no result only errors
that are saying ascii' codec can't decode byte 0x80 in position 13: ordinal not in range(128) .
even if i try with iso-8859-15 encoding witch normaly support the euro symbol.
the system is not installed with Xorg because it is a server, can that be the problem ?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

It could be your font.  Try the Euro character in GIMP using the same font to see if the font supports that codepoint.

Also check your code to see if you are giving PIL a `unicode` string or a byte-string.  [The documentation](http://effbot.org/imagingbook/imagefont.htm) says you should do it like this:

```
font = ImageFont.truetype("symbol.ttf", 16, encoding="symb")
draw.text((0, 0), unichr(0xF000 + 0xAA))
```

The Euro sign is `unichr(0x20AC)`.  Note that `unichr` returns a `unicode` string not a `str` (bytes) string.

Comment: when i use this :   fontA = ImageFont.load(os.path.join(fontpath,'courO24.pil'))
tmpDraw.text((0, 0), unichr(0x20AC + 0xAA),font=fontA)

Comment: I think the last part of your comment got cut off.  What happens when you try that?